# Не загружается css в Open Server

Tags: html, css, openserver, link

Почему-то не грузятся css в Open Server на втором компьютере, а на основном всё замечательно работает ! Не могу понять в чём проблема...

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/reg.css" />    
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/reg2.css" />
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Примерно так это выглядит:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">
<head>  
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <title>Название</title>
 <meta name="description" content="Содержание"/>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/reg.css" /> 
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/reg2.css" />
 <script type="text/javascript" src="js/libs/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="js/libs/prefixfree.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="js/reg.js"></script>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lobster" rel="stylesheet"/>
 <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Comfortaa" rel="stylesheet">
 <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto+Slab" rel="stylesheet"/>
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"/>
 <link rel="shortcut icon" href="ico/favicon.png"/>
</head>
```

Comment: Вы пробовали открыть линк css/reg.css на прямую через браузер? Пишет ли сервер какую то ошибку? Что в логах?

Comment: @PavelBereznichenko Да пробовал, в консоли браузера нет никаких ошибок, ничего ! Хотя если открыть сайт через IE там они грузятся, хоть и криво...

Comment: а через нормальные браузер грузятся?

Comment: А в Open Server последние строки такие:
Apache запросы:
`default: 127.0.0.1 [10/Jan/2017:17:05:41 +0700] "-" 408 - "-" "-"`(штук 5)
Apache отладка:
`[Tue Jan 10 16:14:38.745830 2017] [ssl:warn] [pid 4136:tid 324] AH01909: default:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name`

Comment: @PavelBereznichenko Через Chrome не грузится, а других браузеров нету.

Comment: То есть, если  в Хроме зайти в View Page Source и кликнуть на ссылку с стилем то файл не открывается?

Comment: @PavelBereznichenko Там просто такой папки нет...

Comment: Можете показать весь кусок кода до <body> ?

Comment: Попробуйте сделать так 
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" "css/reg.css" />
или
<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' 'css/reg.css' />
Мне кажется проблема из за того что не стоит типа
и не закрыт линк еще <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Comfortaa" rel="stylesheet">

Comment: @PavelBereznichenko Не помогло(( Даже если убрать линк со шрифтами .Странно, что на основном компьютере работает , если там какая-то ошибка.

Comment: проверьте права на доступ к папке проекта,
может быть стоит проверить .htaccess

Comment: Откройте инспектор в браузере, перейдите на вкладку "Сеть / Network", обновите страницу. Посмотрите в отчете по каких адресам браузер реально запрашивает css файлы. Сравните эти пути с реальными в вашей системе.

Comment: Он запрашивает по адресу http://classroom/css/reg.css

Comment: У меня запрашивает по http:// localhost:port/server/css/style/style.css
я подозреваю что у вас не правильно идет запрос

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Во-первых, в `link` должен быть обязательный атрибут `href`;

На локальном задавайте ссылки через `./catalog/filename.ext`

Ваш пример:

`<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" "css/reg2.css"/>`;

Хороший пример (рабочий):

`<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./css/reg2.css"/>;`

Лучший пример (должен работать):

```
$path = __DIR__; // если "file name".php
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" "<?php echo $path; ?>/css/reg2.css"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Мне кажется вот так должно заработать, у вас еще не хватает символа закрытия тэга в 13 строке

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">
<head>  
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Название</title>
    <meta name="description" content="Содержание"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" "css/reg.css"/>  
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" "css/reg2.css"/>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/libs/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/libs/prefixfree.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/reg.js"></script>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lobster" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Comfortaa" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto+Slab" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"/>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="ico/favicon.png"/>
</head>
```

Comment: Теперь у меня ещё больше вопросов ! Я так понимаю у меня css работал, но не полностью ! Так как div, который является всплывающим окном в css имел display:none и он был скрыт, но после вашего исправления css вообще почему-то перестал работать !

Comment: @Mr.Proper, попробуйте создать файл в блокноте temp.html и записать в него этот код, и немного body, и открыть его без запуска сервера, есть вероятность что сервер путает пути ссылок

Comment: Теперь здесь какая-то ошибка:
`XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///C:/OpenServer/domains/classroom/css/reg2.css. Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https, chrome-extension-resource.`
Почему-то ругается на плагин, который сам подставляет префиксы в css

Comment: @Mr.Proper возможно антивирус не пускает? (это если не каспер стоит) Если на вашем сайте есть php или скрипты, то они работать НЕ БУДУТ! Все потому, что многие антивирусы, например Касперский и другие, расценивают запуск Open Server как вирус и блокируют работу всех скриптов.

Answer (score 0):

Тоже по умолчанию OpenServer не хотел грузить js и css (копия сайта на Drupal 7). Целый день пропарился с конфигами апача. Забил и просто сменил в настройках OpenServer'a на Apache + nginx и все заработало без всяких настроек.

Answer (score 0):

У меня была похожая проблема из за __ в стилях. Локально и на апаче работало, а на nginx нет.
К примеру: `<div class="pop__content-block">` не работало, страница обрезалась на середине (месте где появлялся класс с двумя нижними подчеркиваниями).
Так `<div class="pop_content-block">` (с одним нижним подчеркиванием) заработало.