# Почему через некоторое время не работает css?

Tags: css, файлы

Когда загружаю файлы html и css на Open Server то css через некоторое время перестаёт работать. Например, вчера я писал стили и всё работало, но сегодня я должен создать новый файл чтоб всё заработало опять, потому что когда пишу в старом файле и обновляю браузер ничего не срабатывает. В чём может быть проблема? И да когда файлы не на локальном сервере, а просто так то всё хорошо и нет такой проблемы.

Comment: shift+F5 кэш обновляли?

Comment: Нет, почему то даже не подумал, сейчас попробую

Comment: @Dizzy221, в хроме вроде `ctrl + f5`

Comment: @Cactus в хроме и так и так можно)

Comment: Пробовал и так и так, ничего не обновляется

Comment: @Dizzy221, как по-мне, так после очередного обновления, сталась проблема с этими обновлениями. Вроде раньше не приходилось обновлять так, стили сами по себе работали. А тут такое.. Не приятненько:)

Comment: @Olexandr в режиме инкогнито или в другом браузере такая же проблема?

Comment: @Dizzy221 да в firefox так же

Comment: @Olexandr пути прописаны верно? Почитайте этот вопрос https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/612889/%D0%9D%D0%B5-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B3%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B6%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F-css-%D0%B2-open-server на всякий случай

Comment: @Dizzy221 Да пути прописаны правильно, ведь когда я создам новый файл и закину в него стили со старого то всё работает

Comment: @Olexandr если вы в браузере в этой же вкладке откроете адрес прописанного стиля, он откроется и там будут все изменения что вы внесли?

Comment: Через `style.css?v=2` тоже старая версия?

Answer (score 2):

Попробуйте открывать сайт в **другом** браузере.
Так же попробуйте очистить **кэш** - `ctrl + f5`.

Можете попробовать запретить кэширование: [вот так.](http://searchengines.guru/showthread.php?t=108804)

---

**Еще вариант:**
Во время разработки сайта открывайте консоль браузера. На вкладке `"Сеть" ("Network")` есть галочка `"Отключить кеш" ("Disable cache")`. Если эта галка включена и консоль открыта - браузер не будет ничего кешировать. Причем это касается только той вкладки, в которой открыта консоль, остальные будут работать в штатном режиме.

[Подробней о проблеме.](https://ospanel.io/forum/viewtopic.php?t=3117)